# Program with SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER Function Only Changes the Desktop Background to the Color Black when Trying to Change it to an Image using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, wallpaper

I am trying to change the desktop background/wallpaper to a different image with a .png file. Although when I run the program, the background turns to solid black instead.

I am certain that I typed the file name, "ksa.png", correctly in my code to be the image I want to be on my background. I used an if condition to write out the last error on a file when the error occurred and used an else condition to write out "Success" if no errors occurred; but when I run the program, it writes "Success" to the file. I have thought about using a .jpg file instead, thinking that maybe .png files just don't work. I'll give an update when I tried using that.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

int main () {
    const wchar_t *filenm = L"ksa.png";
    std::ofstream log;
    if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)filenm, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE) == FALSE) {
        log.open("log.txt");
        log << "Error: " << GetLastError();
        log.close();
    }
    else {
        log.open("log.txt");
        log << "Success";
        log.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, the desktop background is suppose to be set as the image "ksa.png". Instead it's solid black. Any help is appreciated for making this work, thank you.

#### UPDATE

Okay so I updated the code to where it would run a .jpg file and I'm still getting the same result. Also I moved the line `log.open("log.txt")` command before the `SystemParametersInfo()` function like Remy Lebeau suggested and it still writes out "Success" to the file. I'm still having the same problem.
Here is my updated code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

int main () {
    const wchar_t *filenm = L"3.jpg";
    std::ofstream log;
    log.open("log.txt");
    if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)filenm, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE) == FALSE) {
        log << "Error: " << GetLastError();
        log.close();
    }
    else {
        log.open("log.txt");
        log << "Success";
        log.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use a PNG file for the wallpaper.  Use a JPG or BMP file instead. Also, if an error did occur, your call to `log.open("log.txt")` would likely wipe out the error code that `GetLastError()` would have returned.  You need to call `GetLastError()` before opening the log file, or open the log file before calling `SystemParametersInfo()`.

Comment: Where is your image file located? You probably need to use an absolute (fully-qualified) path, not a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

Emmmm,there is a problem with your picture path. I've tried your code. You can't get pictures under relative paths unless you use absolute paths.

Like Cody Gray♦'s judgment .

```
const wchar_t *filenm = L"C:\\Users\\strives\\Desktop\\timg.bmp";
```

Comment: @Wolf Zwinerer If my answer can help you, please mark my answer, which is a great encouragement to me.